# Viewing KML/KMZ file within web browser

Tags: kml, software-recommendations, google-earth, kmz

We work with people that need to view large KML files, but they cannot install Google Earth or any other desktop software. We have tried using earth.google.com, but it does not handle all of the features properly and is very slow. The left-side view you get in the desktop version of Google Earth (with folders, buttons to turn on and off groups of features, etc) needs to be visible and functional too. None of the options we have tried so far seem to do this.

We have been unable to find any solution that does this out of the box, and it looks like we will need to build our own application.

Is there a way to view KML/KMZ data with the folder and layer controls that you get in Google Earth but within a browser?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a streaming service such as [Amazon AppStream](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) to host the desktop version of Google Earth in the cloud.  The interface is streamed to the browser as video, essentially.

Obviously this would have an associated cost for hosting, but wouldn't require you to build a full application from scratch.